# XCode 8でGameKit.frameworkでのビルドエラー

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

iOSでGameKitを使用してGameCenterのランキング機能を使ったアプリを作っています。
使用言語はObjective-Cです。
Xcode７まではビルド通って、アプリが実行できました。
Xcode8にしてビルドすると、自分のファイルでは無いファイルでビルドエラーが出ます。

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Headers/GKGameSessionEventListener.h:23:102: Too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
```

エラーが起きているのは

GKGameSessionEventListener.h の

```
+ (void)addEventListener:(NSObject<GKGameSessionEventListener> *)listener NS_SWIFT_NAME(add(listener:)) NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED;
```

部分です。

このビルドエラーを回避する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。お役に立つかどうかわかりませんが、報告します。

自分用のマクロ add　というものを定義していました。
　
`#define add(data, val, limit) {if(++data >= limit)data = limit;}`

このaddをコメントアウトしました。
それにより、このビルドエラーは出なくなりました。